# Rewriting URL of WordPress in a Subdirectory

Tags: redirects, wordpress, apache

I am renting some webspace and a domain from BlueHost.com on which I run a WordPress site. Let's call it `example.com`. WordPress is installed in the root folder.

As I can run multiple sites on this webspace, I installed a second WordPress site in a subdirectory: `example.com/wp2`.

I furthermore own a second domain - let's call it `example.net` - which is rented from nearlyfreespeech.com. I therefore created a `.htaccess` file which forwards all traffic from `example.net` to `example.com/wp2`.

My problem: I can't figure out how to rewrite the URL to show `example.net` once a user has reached that WordPress site. Right now, the URL changes to `example.com/wp2` after accessing the site via `example.net`.

Many tutorials point out that a `.htaccess` file should be placed in the root directory of `example.com` to rewrite the URL. But as I already have a separate WordPress site sitting in that root directly, that doesn't seem to work for me.

How can I rewrite that URL so that people who access the second WordPress site via `example.net` keep seeing that URL?

Comment: I wouldn't put different domains in subdirerectories of each other.   I'm not sure what type of hosting plan you have, but maybe you can edit virtual host files?  If so you can point the second domain to a different folder that isn't within the document root of the first domain.

Comment: " I therefore created a .htaccess file ..." - so you also have hosting for the domain `second.com` at `nearlyfreespeech.com`?

Comment: @MrWhite Right! I originally used nearlyfreespeech to host my sites but as I ran into some problems there, I moved to a different provider. 

Might it make sense to transfer the domain, too? Would that solve any of the problems I have?

Answer (score 1):

If `example.net` points to the second WP installation in the subdirectory `/wp2`, the corresponding `.htaccess` should be placed in the `wp2` folder, not one level above.

Comment: The htaccess in root of domain.com rewrites the URLs for the first WP installation, accessible via Domain.com. The root for WP2 is not domain.com, but Domain.com/wp2

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But even after trying out different ways of rewriting the URL in the .htaccess file and lots of Google I can't get this to work.

Either I end up with error messages, nothing at all happens, or I produce a redirect instead of a rewrite.

Comment: What URL is specified in WP2?

Answer (score 0):

> As I can run multiple sites on this webspace, I installed a second WordPress site in a subdirectory: `example.com/wp2`.

The ability to "run multiple sites on this webspace" is most probably referring to the ability to have multiple domain names pointing to your webspace, rather than having multiple instances of a CMS installed (which you could do anyway, regardless of whether "multiple sites" are permitted or not).

The multiple domains are achieved by creating an "Addon Domain" or "Domain Alias" at BlueHost.com (cPanel terminology, but the idea is the same regardless of the hosting control panel used).

An "Addon Domain" and "Domain Alias" are very similar. A "Domain Alias" is essentially just that, an *alias* for your main domain and usually points at the main domains document root. An "Addon Domain" on the other hand has its own document root and can point directly to a subdirectory (for example).

You should probably be created `example.net` as an "Addon Domain" on your BlueHost.com hosting account that points directly to the `/wp2` subdirectory.

> I furthermore own a second domain - let's call it `example.net` - which is rented from nearlyfreespeech.com. I therefore created a `.htaccess` file which forwards all traffic from `example.net` to `example.com/wp2`.

Simply 3xx "redirecting" the request from `example.net` to `example.com/wp2` is naturally going to expose `example.com`. Alternatively, you could create a reverse proxy at your nearlyfreespeech.com (NFS.com) hosting and proxy the requests to `example.com/wp2` - but this is a lot more work, requires a hosting account at NSF.com with server-level access.

Instead, you should forget the hosting/`.htaccess` at NFS.com and point the `example.net` directly at your `example.com` account (having created the "Addon Domain" as mentioned above), by either:

- Create DNS `A` records for `example.net` (and `www.example.net`?) that point to the IP address of your `example.com` server.
- Change the NAMESERVERS on `example.net` to point to BlueHost.com and control the DNS at BlueHost.com instead. BlueHost.com will have already created the necessary `A` (and `CNAME`) records at the time you created the "Addon Domain".

If you want you can also *transfer* the domain to BlueHost.com (and change NAMESERVERS in the process) if you wanted to finish with NFS.com completely. This is entirely up to you. You don't need to change registrar in order to use the domain at BlueHost.com.

No additional `.htaccess` files or directives are required in this scenario.

> Many tutorials point out that a `.htaccess` file should be placed in the root directory of `example.com` to rewrite the URL.

Those tutorials would seem to be referring to something else?